# How can I use jCarousel with swipe event in drupal for touch screen?

Tags: javascript

In my project, I used the jCarousel module and View slideshow module for my items.When I tested with mobile devices,I saw there is a problem for navigation. I can't scroll well . So I would like to add some script for this problem.I already added some script for My View SLide Show from this website (https://gist.github.com/eristoddle/5011106). Fortunately , it works well with View Slideshow but it not works with jCarousel. I need to know which script is appropriate with my problem. Please let me know how can I do? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

- [**Swipe event**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_event_swipe)
- [**jQuery.event.swipe**](http://stephband.info/jquery.event.swipe/)

On swipe you can trigger left and right navigation event.

Reference:

- [**Swipe**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/)